# Vagrant 1.9.6 hangs on command "vagrant ssh"

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows, vagrant-ssh

I have vagrant 1.9.6 and oracle virtual box 5.1.22 installed on my system. when I ran vagrant up and tried to switch into vagrant ssh on GIT bash it hangs there and nothing get it to work on me.

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: does it work when you use normal windows command prompt ?

Comment: It's working when I ran it on command prompt. Is there any issue with git bash? If so how can it solve?

Comment: dunno but its referenced here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8739

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by adding this line `export VAGRANT_PREFER_SYSTEM_BIN=1` in my `.bash_profile` file. You can manually create this file on windows and place it on your home directory.

Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9143#issuecomment-343311263)

Comment: It works for me. Probably you should check where you placed the file and also consider restarting your PC afterwards